# Where is the bluetooth/bluetooth.h located in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, ibeacon, bluez

I want to build a c file based on BlueZ but seems no bluetooth.h file in my system.

```
fatal error: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: No such file or directory
```

I am sure the bluetooth dongle is running correctly and I have built Bluez successfully.

**Update**

For my case, I find the bluetooth.h in /user/include/bluetooth folder

Comment: So you know where bluetooth.h is, but you're c compiler doesn't. You need to include /user/include/bluetooth in your compilers directory search

Comment: This isn't necessarily the issue you face, but on some linux distributions, there's the binary version of packages which provide runtime support, and then a separate "-dev" package which contains what you need to link your own programs against provided libraries.  Perhaps you don't have the -dev package for bluez installed.  (Yes, I know you found a header - but there may be more to the puzzle)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes. I think you are right. Will try to add the dev library.

Comment: @user3288829 will that be too tedious? I mean if I change the path later I have to change every file's include path.

Comment: Hopefully `/user/include/bluetooth` is a typo in your post.  If not, then your probablem is that you accidentally ended up with something installed under /user what belongs under /usr where it should be picked up as part of standard include paths.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You need to install libbluetooth-dev package for compiling your code

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
```

That should install the bluetooth header files.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this without installing this file? I only need to compile , i am not allowed to install it.

Comment: Yes download and extract .deb file and  provide include directory to CLFAGS=-I/path/to/libbluetooth-dev/headerfiles while configuring BlueZ

Comment: I am using bluetooth APIs in Qt which in turn uses bluez on linux, do you know what I need to do to link bluez to Qt? thanks. I imagine I still have to execute install with the line you posted.

Comment: @zadane: I don't know actually but you should try Qt Bluetooth http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html

Comment: The solution provided didn't work for me. The reason is that the make file of the official source distribution is searching in the directory `/usr/include`, meanwhile the headers are in `/usr/include/bluetooth`. I had to copy all the headers from the bluetooth directory to `/usr/include`. I hope this help!

Comment: @noun you've messed everything up by doing that. The correct include is `#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>`

Comment: THIS IS ANCIENT Installing sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev PACKAGE  is  normal  . standard  Linux install.. LOCATING the actual library to tell compiler to link with has not been answered.

Answer (score 10):

For Fedora, you can use:

```
sudo dnf install bluez-libs-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS 7:

```
sudo yum install bluez-libs-devel
```