# Bluetooth Library for BlueZ (Windows)

Tags: linux, bluetooth, download, bluez, intel-edison

What is the Windows equivalent for Linux's libbluetooth2-dev? I'm trying to run simple_scan.c for a BlueZ-enabled bluetooth scan on my Intel Edison but I need the bluetooth library. This is the solution for linux: [Where is the bluetooth/bluetooth.h located in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436909/where-is-the-bluetooth-bluetooth-h-located-in-linux). But where can I download an equivalent library on my Windows device?

Comment: do you mean windows pc or windows phone ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bluetooth in Windows is a completely different animal.  BlueZ is not supported in Windows at all.  That simple_scan.c you're referring to will also not run on Windows.  I'm working on a project to read Heart Rate Monitors and we found it's going to be a royal pain to do in Windows (see example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95)) so we went Linux with our project and are using BlueZ with Qt 5.5.

Comment: I am also fighting with this animal, trying my best, Already done with MacOS, iOS, Android and Linux but very difficult to do in Windows

Comment: I am also wondering if there is a bluetooth development package for Windows. Ideally, I would like a cross platform package, but it appears that no such package exists. Can somebody please prove me wrong? It appears that this is the link that provides instructions for bluetooth programming in Windows `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-start-page`.

Answer (score 0):

I am turning crazy with the same thing. By now I have found the following:

- Seems the valid ways are tinyB from intel-iot-devkit or Eclipse Kura (which is osgi and not compatible with spring). They are as faithful as lack of information. Those are the available options and they seem based on Bluez for unix.
- There are wrappers around GATT with SmartGattLib (movisens) and nrjavaserial (neuronrobotics), but no binary info.
- There is a bluecove implementation that works cool for bluetooth. Includes binaries...but no support for Bluetooth 4.0+ or GATT Services.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.ultreia/bluecove -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.ultreia</groupId>
    <artifactId>bluecove</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The cherry on the top of the cake is what you can find at https://community.openhab.org/t/bluetooth-le-smart-bluetooth-mesh-integration/50805/6

They say the following which is of interest for this question:

- "Since there is no Java support for BT, I would like to interface the BlueZ stack via DBus, similar to the existing BLE binding."
- "The binding that I develop/support is based on the Java Bluetooth Manager 26 that is also developed and supported by OH community. As you said, there is not BT support in Java, so the BluetoothManager is supposed to fill that gap. We tried to design it in a such way that it is easily extendable. It supports various “transport” layers, e.g. TinyB (over DBus), BlueGiga and native DBus (it is being developed now)."

Comment: Please focus on answering. Asking questions is for questions, or maybe comments, when you have that privilege. If you do not consider this to be an answer, i.e. if the asking part was relevant in your opinion, then please delete the post.